# Laravel dropzone.js is undefined with template

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I have a Laravel project and I use this template :

https://wrappixel.com/demos/admin-templates/monster-admin/main/form-dropzone.html

In my project I put my dropzone form and it works like I want, but I want to add a success event when a file is upload. So in my custom.js I do :

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('../vendor/monster_admin/assets/plugins/dropzone-master/dist/dropzone.js');

$( document ).ready(function() {
  //dropzone.js file upload success
  Dropzone.options.dropzone = {
    init: function() {
      console.log('1');
    }
  };
});
```

But I receive the error : Dropzone is not defined.

If I try on the template page to open the console and access Dropzone object it's work but not on my page.

Anybody know how to access the dropzone object?

If needed, my html form :

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['admin.upload', class_basename($model), $model->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal dropzone dz-clickable', 'id' => 'dropzone', 'files' => TRUE]) !!}

    <div class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div></form>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

EDIT :

I found this :

```
 if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module !== null) {
    module.exports = Dropzone;
  } else {
    window.Dropzone = Dropzone;
  }
```

So my project enter the if but I want to go in the else (without changing template file). Anybody know what is this module thing ? Not used excepted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution, this if

```
 if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module !== null) {
    module.exports = Dropzone;
  } else {
    window.Dropzone = Dropzone;
  }
```

Export Dropzone in a module, I need to include (top of the file and not in document.ready) this module in my custom.js with

```
import * as Dropzone from '../vendor/monster_admin/assets/plugins/dropzone-master/dist/dropzone.js';
```

It's a node.js thing (I think cause I read it on tutorial but I never use node.js).

Comment: If I do this, I get `Dropzone already attached.` and `Cannot set property 'dropzoneUpload' of undefined` in console.